# « soit » : Comment a-t-il evolué pour se séparer ?

Tags: étymologie

> [soit](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/soit) =  {verbe} [V]1.     (Mathématiques) Supposons que … est.
>   Note d’usage : Introduit ou pose un nouvel objet mathématique.
>
> {conjunction} 
>   [C]1. Ou. Quelquefois, au lieu de répéter *soit*, on met *ou*.
>
> [C]2. Autrement dit.
>
> = {Adverbe} [A]1. D’accord, admettons.
>
> [[Littré]](http://www.littre.org/definition/soit) Anciennement, alors qu'on avait le sentiment que **soit** était un verbe,
>   on le mettait au pluriel quand la construction l'exigeait ;
>   et, quand la phrase était au passé, au lieu de **soit**, on se servait de **fust**, **fut**.

Je sais déjà que « soit » constitute le troisième personne du présent du subj. du verbe être. Pourtant, ni [CNRTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/soit) et ni les citations ci-dessus n'exposent et n'expliquent : Comment interpréter cette étymologie pour comprendre comment les sauts sémantiques se sont écartés du sens littéral original ? Comment rapprocher les acceptions ultérieures (figurées)  des acceptions originales ?

Plutôt qu’éplucher chaque sens à part, je m’enquiers de la vue d’ensemble,
(à savoir) de l’acception basale, de « soit » (de la même manière que [cette explication](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/24102/50720) profite de l’acception basale de ‘tally’). Ainsi, quelle métaphore recouvre, rapproche les acceptions ultérieures ci-dessus, et explique les changements sémantiques?

Comment: Être (racine de soit) est vrai dans toute situation (sinon c'est le néant, le non soit et donc le vide) quelque soit l'étiquette grammaticale apposée : on donne vie à une entité (supposons...),  transférée vers une autre (*ou*), ou *admise* comme vrai (pour reprendre vos exemples). C'est l'outil dont se sert l'imagination lorsqu'elle crée, manipule ou examine des entités qui peuvent représenter une réalité.  ...sauf que ce n'est pas là une explication académique. :)

Answer (score 1):

Je ne trouve pas que les différentes acceptations s'éloignent fortement l'une de l'autre. En français, nombreux sont les mots ont des significations légèrement différentes, mais ici on assiste plutôt à une simplification.

Pour poser quelque chose, on emploie en effet couramment le verbe "être"

> Que la lumière soit !

Ce qui donne également

> Que soit la lumière !

Et partant

> Soit la lumière, il n'y a plus d'obscurité !

Ceci explique les différentes formes du verbe que vous citez (Soient, fut, fust) qui ont disparu du langage courant. A noter également que le "t" de soit se prononce dans le dernier cas.

Pour le second sens, on joue avec la répétition du "soit" (on pose deux fois), ce qui n'est pas non plus contradictoire avec l'étymologie.

Enfin, l'adverbe provient également de l'utilisation du verbe "être" :

> Qu'il en soit ainsi ! Ainsi soit-il !

qui devient "soit" pour marquer son accord